# using POST with Angularjs and Google App Engine Python Server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, angularjs

I have a problem here.

I have been using $resource to do simple GET, but recently i have a large amount of data to send to the server, but gives a 414 Error URI too large. I know that one of the solution is to use POST instead of GET.

I tried to search for solutions such as $http.post and passing parameters to $http, but to no avail. Can someone give me a tutorial on how should i do it?

Edit:

Here is what i have done:

```
    var data_2 = $.param({'method':"update_proj",
            'proj_id': proj_id,
            'ptitle': project.title,
            'pdescription': p_desc,
            'pexposure': tech,
            'pcompany': project.company,
            'pteamsize':project.teamsize,
            'ppoc': project.poc,
            'pemail': c_email,
            'pcontact': project.contact,
            'pimg':project.img,
            'pvideo':project.video,
            'prskill': rskills,
            'poutcome': project.outcome});

    $http({method:'update_proj',
      url: "http://osmosisgal.appspot.com/update_proj", 
      data: data_2,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
    .success(function(data,status){
     ...
    });
```

Here is my python code on GAE:

```
    class ActionHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
       def update_project(self):
           proj_id = self.request.POST["proj_id"]
               .
               .
               .
```

But i still have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~osmosisgal/1.366101252356646323/new_backend.py", line 1274, in update_project
    proj_id = self.request.POST["proj_id"]
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1/webob/multidict.py", line 312, in __getitem__
    return self._decode_value(self.multi.__getitem__(self._encode_key(key)))
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1/webob/multidict.py", line 568, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("No key %r: %s" % (key, self.reason))
KeyError: "No key 'proj_id': Not a form request"
```

Comment: From the [$http page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http): `$http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);`.  Did you try searching SO for some examples?: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangularjs+%5D+%24http.post

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) you can see that method is getting the type of method and not the url, in first place.

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: '/someUrl', data: my_data}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

For you data you can create a json object with pairs, key-value and pass it to the function like above.

Also do not forget to pass $http in your controller definition.

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {...};
```

Comment: i tried, but could not work. it gives me these errors:
OPTIONS http://osmosisgal.appspot.com/update_proj 500 (Internal Server Error) 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://osmosisgal.appspot.com/update_proj. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Try after data to pass variable, `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. Initially I did not host all my static files in GAE, after i hosted it, everything works.